# Tastypie ImportError when importing resources

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I have created a couple of Tastypie API's before so I'm particularly confused as to what is causing this issue.

resources.py

```
class PrettyJSONSerializer(Serializer):
    json_indent = 4

    def to_json(self, data, options = None):
        options = options or {}
        data = self.to_simple(data, options)
        return simplejson.dumps(data, cls = json.DjangoJSONEncoder, sort_keys = True, ensure_ascii = False, indent = self.json_indent)


####################################


class RankedResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Ranked.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        serializer = PrettyJSONSerializer()
        resource_name = 'ranked'
        authorization = Authorization()

class StudentResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Student.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        serializer = PrettyJSONSerializer()
        resource_name = 'student'
        authorization = Authorization()



class UnrankedResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Unranked.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        serializer = PrettyJSONSerializer()
        resource_name = 'unranked'
        authorization = Authorization()
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from tastypie.api import Api
from django.contrib import admin
from app.api.resources import RankedResource, UnrankedResource

admin.autodiscover()

v1_api = Api(api_name = 'v1')
v1_api.register(RankedResource())
#v1_api.register(UnrankedResource())
#v1_api.register(StudentResource())
```

The RankedResource works perfectly, however if I try to import either of the the other two resources (UnrankedResource or StudentResource) it returns an `ImportError: cannot import name UnrankedResource`. I've triple checked my spelling to make sure that wasn't causing the issue and I don't believe it is.

What could be causing one resource to work but all others to fail? I'm completely stumped, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:
I've tried renaming the resource several times and for whatever reason it only works when it is named RankedResource. Any other resource name returns the same `ImportError`

Comment: I remember having a problem like this a year ago. Sorry if I'm being totally unclear and not providing any answer, but what I remember is that I wasn't using the same name in the models and in the resource (`related_name` in resources.py and `verbose_name` (not sure if it's that or another name option) in models.py).

Maybe you should check something like that...

Comment: The solution ended up being rewrite the resources file again and it worked.

Comment: That could be *.pyc files next time try to clean them.